# Azure Virtual Device (AVD) - Intune Configuration Policies (assigned vs user) do not apply

Tags: android-virtual-device, azure-virtual-machine, intune

I've successfully created a VM using a hostpool for AVD. I can connect to it using the new RDP+AAD creds, or my RMM tools and a local account. From Intune I have a number of options from the settings catalog I am trying to apply using a configuration policy - however I am unable to get anything with the suffix (User) to work here...
If I build two settings catalog configuration profiles I can assign device settings vs this device group, and I assign (User) settings to "all users" and filter for this device. But the AVD VM never actually attempts to receive this user-assigned policy.

Am I unable to use a user-group based assignment against an AVD?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Intune user scope configuration for Azure Virtual Desktop multi-session VMs recently became GA (generally available).

Device scope configuration for Windows 11 and Windows 10 multi-session was already GA since April and enabling users to manage VMs using Microsoft Intune settings catalog and the Endpoint security blade.
This new update enables you to configure user scope policies using settings catalog, configure user certificates, and configure PowerShell scripts in user context.

The following capabilities are now generally available on Azure Virtual Desktop with Microsoft Intune:

1. Manage device and user scope configuration for multi-session session host VMs using the settings catalog and Endpoint Security in the Microsoft Endpoint Manager (Intune) admin center.
2. Easily create new endpoint security policies, like you do for physical devices, by choosing the Windows 10, Windows 11, and Windows Server platform.
3. Manage multi-session VMs created in the Azure Public and Azure Government (US GCC High and DoD environments) clouds.

We have published a blog post on this topic. Please go through the below link for further details.

[Microsoft Intune user scope configuration for AVD multi-session VMs](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-virtual-desktop-blog/microsoft-intune-user-scope-configuration-for-azure-virtual/ba-p/3667410)
[AVD multi-session with Intune](https://docs.microsoft.com/mem/intune/fundamentals/azure-virtual-desktop-multi-session)

Comment: Using the settings catalog and applying any policy with the tag (User) is marked as "Not applicable" after the policy is applied to the VM. Are these still not yet working?\